# How to make RootStore with Mobx6

Tags: reactjs, mobx

so mobx 6 is out and i am trying to implement a basic store like that :

```
export class AuthStore {
  rootStore
  value
  constructor(rootStore) {
    makeObservable(this, {
      value:observable
    })
    this.rootStore = rootStore
  }
}
```

and

```
class RootStore {
  constructor () {
    this.authStore = new AuthStore(this)
  }
}

const stores = new RootStore()
```

and i am getting an error : Cannot decorate undefined property: 'value'

but if i will take the AuthStore outside the RootStore

```
const authStore = new AuthStore()
```

every thing working fine .. i tried to read more then once the mobx 6t docs but there is nothing about it

would like to know what i am doing wrong !
thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the error message -

> Cannot decorate **undefined** property: 'value'

Your value is `undefined`, and mobx takes issue with that. The easy fix is to initialise your value to null:

```js
export class AuthStore {
  rootStore
  value = null;
  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore

    makeObservable(this, {
      value:observable
    })
  }
}
```

It's easy to see why you've fallen victim to this - the [mobx documentation itself](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html) actually leads you to believe that what you did is kosher -

```
import { makeObservable, observable, computed, action } from "mobx"

class Doubler {
    value

    constructor(value) {
        makeObservable(this, {
            value: observable,
            double: computed,
            increment: action
        })
        this.value = value
    }

    get double() {
        return this.value * 2
    }

    increment() {
        this.value++
    }
}
```

But if you try this code out, you get the same error :|.

> if i will take the AuthStore outside the RootStore every thing working fine

This threw me a little - I couldn't explain why this would happen! But [I couldn't reproduce it either](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-leftpad-t1j4o?file=/src/stores.js) - I got the same behaviour no matter where the auth store was initialised.

For some more background - mobx is using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` under the hood to try and work out what the `value` property is - when the value is `undefined`, this returns:

```
Object { value: undefined, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
```